# Does the refresh token expire?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, autodesk, autodesk-forge

There is an expiration time (in seconds) for the access token, but does the refresh token also has an expiration time?

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiJTV042SjVUQUVSQUIiLCJleHAiOjE0OTMzODc1NDEsInNjb3BlIjpbImRhdGE6d3JpdGUiLCJkYXRhOmNyZWF0ZSIsImRhdGE6cmVhZCIsImJ1Y2tldDpyZWFkIiwiYnVja2V0OmNyZWF0ZSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJVc1pEVUJoQUlzbHNBa0g2emtBaU02UWlXWU5reElNbyIsImdyYW50X2lkIjoic2tmNmR3OGFzbjl5eGM4RG5MM0ZYemVsZkhwTG5LN3IiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2F1dG9kZXNrLmNvbS9hdWQvand0ZXhwNjAiLCJqdGkiOiJ3V2tHYXY0djhRcHU3emlHV0R0eXZRR3J3MklEVU1FZFRRNWZlaGtlbFVnbnhDa2RZQW5Gakp4V09ldHNscUcxIn0.r2Tk3L6fy10pr5PRIFx9jp6cNB0qXMx0j0v0R47SsgQ",
  "refresh_token": "Qz5azGOgskSE9wFhIn2NyzA7JxQkkhjtmCK8nLn10U",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Refresh tokens can expire but it depends upon the way the authentication server is implemented when they will expire.    You should be able to safely assume hat a refresh token is extremely long lived.

> [Refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) carry the information necessary to get a new access
>   token. In other words, whenever an access token is required to access
>   a specific resource, a client may use a refresh token to get a new
>   access token issued by the authentication server. Common use cases
>   include getting new access tokens after old ones have expired, or
>   getting access to a new resource for the first time. Refresh tokens
>   can also expire but are rather long-lived. Refresh tokens are usually
>   subject to strict storage requirements to ensure they are not leaked.
>   They can also be blacklisted by the authorization server.

I was not able to find any information on [autodesk](http://ttps://developer.autodesk.com) site as to when they expire refresh tokens. Normally the user who authenticated you has the power to revoke the authentication and some systems expire tokens which have not been used in six months.

Comment: @DalmTo is right - the expiring for the refresh token is extremely long, it only expires once you use it, or the user revoke access to your app.

Comment: A refreshToken should not expire when used it can be used any number of times to gain a new access token

Comment: @DalmTo - well in the case of Forge it does - when you use it an new accessToken and a new refreshToken will be issued.

Comment: I have never seen that it may depend on how the authentication server is implemented it's not part of the rfc for Oauth

Comment: @cyrille extremely long, meaning? 1 week? 1 month? I suppose I can store it and use it (and replace it with the new one when using it), so that the user doesn't have to log in too often.

Comment: @PaulMS it depends upon how autoDesk has it implemented i was unable to find any information on their site.  Which i would take to mean that they don't expire it, however I suggest you contact them to be sure.   Either way you should implement a check that if it fails that you prompt your user for reauthentication.

Comment: Thanks DaImTo, the check it already implemented. I was asking @cyrille because he is Autodesk :)

Comment: @PaulMS, today the expire time for the refresh-token is set for 15 days

Comment: I just checked in expire time was 1 hour.

Comment: Access tokens expire in one hour.   Refresh tokens expire in 7 days if the app is still in testing.